# Через тире или запятую нужно писать: "обновить, перезаписать старую запись на новою" или "обновить - перезаписать старую запись на новою"?

Tags: пунктуация

"Обновить, перезаписать старую запись на новою" или "обновить - перезаписать старую запись на новою"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Это от смысла зависит. Если вы даете определение понятия "обновить", то через тире. Если у вас идет перечисление, то через запятую.

Дайте контекст, о чем вообще речь идет. Чем больше текста есть сопутствующего текста - тем лучше, идеально - вообще весь фрагмент.